# Index.Rmd without first-level heading

Tags: r, bookdown

I have a simple bookdown project with several Rmd files, one file per chapter plus an index.Rmd.

#### index.Rmd

```
---
title: Title
author: My name
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
documentclass: book
---
```

#### 01-chapter1.Rmd

```
# Some stuff
```

etc...

I want my index file mostly empty because all the chapter files are interchangeable, for now at least. I don't plan to have any short introduction. I **might** want to add some preface, but that breaks everything. Bookdown wants me to start with a chapter in the index.Rmd

#### Result

I can generate pdf and epub without any problem but for html or gitbook I get an error:

> In split_chapters(output, gitbook_page, number_sections, split_by,  : 
>   You have 6 Rmd input file(s) but only 5 first-level heading(s). Did
>   you forget first-level headings in certain Rmd files?

and the generated book only consist of an error message:

> /home/milo/Documents/bookdown_project/_book/index.html not found