# How to have Frontpage Image before chapter title and book title?

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown, blogdown

Is that possible to  have  FrontPage Image
a) BEFORE first chapter title,
b) BEFORE book title?

Currently the only way to include any frontpage image seems to be AFTER the first-level (non-empty)  heading, like below:

````
---
knit: "bookdown::render_book" 
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
documentclass: book
author: "Me Mine"
title: "«My Book»"  
---

# Frontpage

```{r, echo=FALSE, out.width="60%", fig.align = "center"}
knitr::include_graphics( "nice-frontpage-image.jpg" )
)

# Introduction
...
````

It would have been so much better if I can do this (without having to have unneeded #Frontpage chapter):

````
---
knit: "bookdown::render_book" 
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
documentclass: book
author: "Me Mine"
title: "«My Book»"  
---

```{r, echo=FALSE, out.width="60%", fig.align = "center"}
knitr::include_graphics( "nice-frontpage-image.jpg" )
)

# Introduction
...
````

And this (i.e. image goes before the title):

```
---
knit: "bookdown::render_book" 
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
documentclass: book
author: "Me Mine"
title: `r knitr::include_graphics( "nice-frontpage-image.jpg" )`
)"\n «My Book»"  
---


# Introduction
...
```

Is that possible?

PS
I found a related still unaswered question here:
[Index.Rmd without first-level heading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58451666/index-rmd-without-first-level-heading)

Comment: Intersting question, I voted up and want to know an answer too...

Comment: I found the answer for B) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62074546/add-image-before-bookdown-title, which links to here: https://community.rstudio.com/t/add-image-before-bookdown-title/67825/5

Comment: Also an easier solution for B) is posted here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62074546/add-image-before-bookdown-title/69932877#69932877. Still searching for solution to A)